# CSS - Auto fill width

Tags: html, css

Here's a js fiddle of what I currently have, I am trying to make it so the boxes all fit within one line and there's a scrollbar that let's people scroll horizontally rather than having the boxes do what they're doing now.

Also, if anyone could get the class panel-body to fill 100% to the height of the page, that'd be awesome ;D

This is using Bootstrap 3.0.2, so the panels are pulled from that.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y55af/

Sample css:

```
.mainContent{
    padding:20px;
}
.workplace_outter{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.workplace_inner{
    width:2000px;
}
.workplace_outter .panel{
    width:300px;
    margin-right:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="workplace_outter">
        <div class="workplace_inner">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Item
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Item Body....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oveflow should say overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "get the white portion of the boxes to fill vertically", but since the panels are already inline-block elements, you can replace the `width` specification on their container with `white-space: nowrap` which will prevent any `inline` or `inline-block` elements from wrapping onto a second line.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y55af/3/), and the relevant code changed:

```css
.workplace_inner{
/*  width:2000px; (don't need anymore) */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: // isn't a valid CSS comment

Comment: I'll update the question, the white part I'm referring to is the panel-body, the div holding the Item Body content. The white-space worked and looks awesome.

Comment: @Alphadelta14 ...and yet no browser I've ever encountered has problems with it. I learn something new every day, I guess.

Comment: @BrianPutt In regards to your second part of the question, I'd suggest you either (a) [search how to make a child element take up 100% of its parent's height](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+100%25+height) and incorporate that into your design, or alternately (if none of those solutions work), (b) open a separate question to get a solution; StackOverflow questions are meant to address single issues at a time, not checklists of problems.